# Initializing value of a key - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyvaluepair

Here I am trying to search through a table view. This has me stumped. I just can't seem to figure out how to initialize the value of "name" so that I can search it. https://github.com/Brandon-316/WOD-Guide

Library sample code:

```
import Foundation

struct BenchmarkWODs {

    static let library = [
        [
            "name": "Angie",
            "exercises": "100 Pull-ups/n100 Push-ups/n100 Sit-ups/n100 Squats",
            "description": "For Time Complete all reps of each exercise before      moving to the next."
        ],
        [
            "name": "Barbara",
            "exercises": "20 Pull-ups\n30 Push-ups\n40 Sit-ups50 Squats\n\nRest precisely three minutes between each round.",
            "description": "5 rounds, time each round"
        ],
        [
            "name": "Chelsea",
            "exercises": "5 Pull-ups\n10 Push-ups\n15 Squats",
            "description": "Each min on the min for 30 min"
        ],
        [
            "name": "Cindy",
            "exercises": "5 Pull-ups\n10 Push-ups\n15 Squats",
            "description": "As many rounds as possible in 20 min"
        ]
    ]

}
```

Detail file code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct WOD {

    var name: String?
    var exercise: String?
    var description: String?

    init(dictionary: [String: String]) {

        name = dictionary["name"]
        exercise = dictionary["exercises"]
        description = dictionary["description"]

    }

}
```

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class BenchmarkWODViewController: UITableViewController,
UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var wodList = [WOD]()
    var searchController : UISearchController?
    var resultsController = UITableViewController()
    var filteredWODS = [String]()

    var results = WOD(dictionary:["name": ""])

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for wodData in BenchmarkWODs.library {
            let wod = WOD(dictionary: wodData)
            wodList.append(wod)
        }

        // Search Bar
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:     self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController?.searchBar
        self.searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self

    }

    // Search Bar Function
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:   UISearchController) {

        let result = results.name
        filteredWODS.append(result!)
        filteredWODS = self.filteredWODS.filter { (result:String) -> Bool in
            return true

        }

        self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wodList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell =     tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BenchmarkCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        let wod = wodList[indexPath.row]

        if let wodName = wod.name {
            cell.textLabel?.text = wodName
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you hate indentation?

Comment: I'm looking at the function `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`, and in it is the line `let result = results.name`. However, `results` is free in the function and refers to the class property `var results = WOD(dictionary:["": ""])`. Does this code even compile?

Comment: Yes it does compile. It crashes when searching however if I do not use name in results. var results = WOD(dictionary:["name": ""])

Comment: Haha I don't. This is fully indented in Xcode I swear. I will make sure and get the indentation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What line is it crashing on?  It does look like you have potential crash here:

```
    let result = results.name
    filteredWODS.append(result!)
```

Where `results` is initially defined with no valid keys:

```
    var results = WOD(dictionary:["": ""])
```

I still don't understand your goal. I'd recommend distilling this down into a simple playground that demonstrates your issue without the context of a view controller.

If I take this code and run it, it crashes on the line mentioned above.

To get it to not crash, you have to remove the force-unwrap on `result!` and use optional binding instead (`if let...`).

Comment: It crashes at let `result = results.name` But if I use `var results = WOD(dictionary:["name": ""])` it does not. I can't seem to draw out the value.

Comment: What do you expect to have happen?

Comment: I'm trying to search through the values of the key `"name"`